# Camera orientation is not changed

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I tried this code for scanning barcode:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-barcode

but it have a bug, when i change orientation of device, camera always has a Protrait orientation...

Any ideas how to fix this ?

I tried to change orientations in this method:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Portrait
    }
```

But it not helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a camera to change the orientation you don't want to use that function. Do this instead...

```
previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
```

What this does is when the camera layer is created it sets the orientation.